# What's the benefit of using fontOptimization in nextJS?

Tags: next.js, webfonts

Doesn't allowing my fonts to be served from https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ make my page load faster and reduce my traffic costs (especially at scale on a large e-comm website)? Why would I want to use NextJS's fontOptimization feature? What does it even mean that it is "optimizing" the fonts?